# select() seems to segfault / kill

Tags: c, select, embedded, segmentation-fault

I am trying to debug an embedded application that uses select() to implement communication timeouts. It is multithreaded using pthreads.

The problem I have is that the application seems to crash on the select() call with either a segmentation fault or "Killed". I tried putting a mutex around the call to no avail.

What could cause select() to crash an application? Or am I in completely the wrong direction?

The call to select() looks like this:

```
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval, timeout, timeout_usec = 0;

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(fd_port, &rfds);

if (use_timeout) {
    timeout = settings_get_int("rs485_timeout", "3");
} else {
    timeout = 0;
    timeout_usec = 100000;
    }

// timeout wait for reply 1000ms
tv.tv_sec = timeout;
tv.tv_usec = timeout_usec; //1000000;

retval = select((int)fd_port+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

Comment: I know I am being very vague. The main question basically, is it possible that select() causes a segfault (possibly through multithreading). Sorry I don't have more info, I am stuck on this for a whole day already.

Comment: Could you put some code?

Comment: Without seeing any code (hint!) this is a shot in the dark, but select tends to confuse people.  Recheck your code where you setup the data structures you feed to select (the FD_ZERO - FD_SET sequence) and also check nfds - quite often people miss that this is the *highest numbered* fd, not the number of fd's

Comment: Just edited the question with some code.

Comment: Also, it runs fine for some time and seem to crash only in a second thread. It started to do this (I am working on version 4 already of the application, all others worked fine) after I parametrised the timeout (among other things).

Comment: Are multiple threads using the same fd_port ?

Comment: select(2) does not have any problems with multithreading, but the code which uses it, often does. Is it the real code? Because this shouldn't crash. Not even in case if fd_port is actually uninitialized and is some random big value (should just return with an error. EFAULT on Linux, according to fs/select.c)

Comment: @fvu yes, even though I try it not to be simultaneously. Main thread starts up the serial communication, checker thread then uses it to get more info. Main thread never uses it again. Note though that the crash starts after it has worked for some time (seems to be a random crash).

Comment: @fork0 yes actual code. If select(2) should have a problem with this, I'll have to look somewhere else. I have put logging around the call and the second log line never came, hence I though select was the culprit.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: it might be not output because it was not flushed before crash. Try using unbuffered output.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: if it is Linux, you can try using valgrind (I assume you already tried debugger). It is usually very good finding such problems.

Comment: @fork0 it is linux, but an embedded device, no valgrind or debugger available.. at least not found yet

Comment: @BartFriederichs Not even gdbserver? A small application which works as a bridge to GDB running on development system

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14285/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-fork0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the randomness of the time and place of the crash, I suspected multithreading problems. I removed all multithreading code and the problems seem to have ceased.

Comment: BTW: does the program use signal handlers? Dynamic allocation?

Comment: Yes, I catch the HUP signal and there is some heap allocation here and there (mostly sqlite3_mprintf(), but sqlite is compiled thread safe)

Answer (score 0):

If your program is actually idle, then crashing in `select` in not particularly unusual if the crash is actually being caused by some external entity, like a process monitor. software watchdog, or the infamous Linux Out of Memory Killer (OOM Killer). Check your system log files to see if you can find an indication that some external function triggered the kill action.

Answer (score 0):

select has the limitation that it can check the sockfds only upto the number 1024.
Please note that 1024 is the maximum value of the sockfd, not the number of sockfds.
Use poll instead, which has no such ,limitations

Please refer 
http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2009/12/22/select-system-call-limitation/
for a more detailed description.